# Unrecognized escape sequence in Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following:

```
String source = "this-is--a-string----";
```

I need to remove consecutive dashes so I am using:

```
String output = Regex.Replace(source, @"\-+", "-");
```

Sometimes I need to remove other duplicated characters so I tried:

```
String source = "this_is__a_string____";
String output = Regex.Replace(source, @"\_+", "_");
```

In this case I got the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: 
One or more errors occurred. (parsing '\_+' - Unrecognized escape sequence \\_.) 
---> System.ArgumentException: parsing '\_+' - Unrecognized escape sequence \\_.
```

How can change my code so I can use it with any character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working as expected:

```
string source = "this_is__a_string____";
string output = Regex.Replace(source, @"_+", "_");
```

Comment: I see you removed the \ from the query string ... So no need for that in the regex, right?

Comment: There is no need to escape _, it has no special meaning in regex, it is literal underscore.

Answer (score 0):

remove the backslash, good to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not master over the replace Pattern:

> *Escape the "Escapes" with a method provided by .net*

This can be achieved by using
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Example:**

```
String source = "this_is__a_string____";
String output = Regex.Replace(source, Regex.Escape(@"\_+"), "_");
```